# XML vs Programmatically for android user interface

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I am a new android app developer. Now with the Android Studio 2.2 version, I would like to know from experienced programmers the better approach to creating the user interface. Which one is more preferable, creating UI with XML or with code. Can you do the same View with both on them, and if not what is the best way? I myself find creating a View with code very annoying. Just wanted to know the best approach that Google recommends.

Comment: Just about nobody creates views programatically for major layouts.  Programatic creation tends to only occur for small dynamic additions, and even then will frequently inflate from xml.

Comment: I saw that this question was answered, but I saw that it was posted in 2012. I was thinking that maybe there must have been some changes since than. That's why I asked the same today.